# Splitting Json array to individual Json elements using Jackson

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

Is there any way to split a given Json array to individual Json elements using **Jackson** library? Say for example, I have this Json array:

```
[
    {
        "key1":"value11", 
        "key2":"value12"
    },
    {
        "key1":"value21", 
        "key2":"value22"
    }
]
```

After splitting I want a list of individual elements like:

```
{
        "key1":"value11", 
        "key2":"value12"
}
```

and

```
{
        "key1":"value21", 
        "key2":"value22"
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A nice solution for this problem is simply to iterate by using the Java 8 Streaming API:s. The `JsonNode` object is `Iterable` where the `spliterator` method is available. So, the following code can be used:

```
public List<String> split(final String jsonArray) throws IOException {
    final JsonNode jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonArray);
    return StreamSupport.stream(jsonNode.spliterator(), false) // Stream
            .map(JsonNode::toString) // map to a string
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); and collect as a List
}
```

Another alternative is to skip the remapping (the call to `toString`) and return a `List<JsonNode>` elements instead. That way you can use the `JsonNode` methods to access the data (`get`, `path` and so on).

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a solution that works:

```
public List<String> split(String jsonArray) throws Exception {
        List<String> splittedJsonElements = new ArrayList<String>();
        ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode jsonNode = jsonMapper.readTree(jsonArray);

        if (jsonNode.isArray()) {
            ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) jsonNode;
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayNode.size(); i++) {
                JsonNode individualElement = arrayNode.get(i);
                splittedJsonElements.add(individualElement.toString());
            }
        }
        return splittedJsonElements;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is in one line:

```
new ObjectMapper().readTree(json).forEach(node -> System.out.println(node.toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out this [API](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readTree%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what the author was asking for.  I split up the JSON list into two strings using the Jackon library toString method.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

...
...
  
String jsonText = "[{\"test\":1},{\"test2\":2}]";
int currentElement = 0;
int elementCount;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

JsonNode jsonObj = mapper.readTree(jsonText);
 
elementCount = jsonObj.size();

while (currentElement<elementCount) {
    System.out.println(jsonObj.get(currentElement).toString());
    currentElement++;
 }
```